# Save IAGSServerConnection connection properties on MXD

Tags: arcgis-engine, arcobjects

I added some server layer from a server connection to mxd. I want to save connection in MXD to don't missed connection from layer when i reopened my MXD.
I had bellow code to connect a server connection.

```
 private void ConnectToArcGISServer(string serverUrl)
        {
        var agsconnection = OpenConnection(serverUrl,txtUser.Text,txtPass.Text);
        IAGSEnumServerObjectName obj = agsconnection.ServerObjectNames;

        IAGSServerObjectName name = obj.Next();
        while (name != null)
        {
            if (name.Type == "ImageServer" || name.Type == "MapServer")
            {
                _serviceList.Add(name.Name, name);
                ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem(name.Name);
                newItem.ImageKey = name.Type;
                lswServiceList.Items.Add(newItem);

        if name.Type== "MapServer")
                    {
                        IAGSServerObjectName osName = (IAGSServerObjectName)name;
                        IName pName = (IName)osName;
                        IMapServer mapServer = (IMapServer)pName.Open();
                        IMapServerLayer mapserverlayer = new MapServerLayerClass();
                        mapserverlayer.ServerConnect(osName, mapServer.DefaultMapName);
                        ClsGeneral.CurrentMapControl.Map.AddLayer((ILayer)mapserverlayer);
                    }
                    else if name.Type== "ImageServer")
                    {
                        IAGSServerObjectName osName = (IAGSServerObjectName)name;

                        IName pName = (IName)osName;
                        ImageServerLayer imageserverlayer = new ImageServerLayerClass();

                        IDataLayer layer = (IDataLayer)imageserverlayer;
                        layer.DataSourceName = pName;



                        ClsGeneral.CurrentMapControl.Map.AddLayer(imageserverlayer);
                    }
            }
        }

    }
private static IAGSServerConnection OpenConnection(string svcUrl,string user,string pass)
        {
            //create a property set to hold connection properties
            var connectionProps = new PropertySet() as IPropertySet;
            //specify the URL for the server
            connectionProps.SetProperty("URL", svcUrl);
            if (user!="" && pass!="")
            {
                connectionProps.SetProperty("USER", user);
                connectionProps.SetProperty("PASSWORD", pass);
            }
            //create a new ArcGIS Server connection factory
            var connectionFactory = (IAGSServerConnectionFactory2)new AGSServerConnectionFactory();

            IAGSServerConnection gisServer = connectionFactory.Open(connectionProps, 0);

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(connectionFactory);
            return gisServer;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

More generally, perhaps the question should be "How can I persist PropertySets in an Mxd?"  If so, use an extension, implementing both `IExtension` and `IPersistVariant`.  See "[How to persist data in a document](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/dotnet/82061861-5b23-47ab-a0fc-d53570105c72.htm)".  It's from 9.3, but still relevant.

Comment: No,That's not work, because of esri documentation: persist the current state of all the non-GIS data or objects used by an application when the document is saved....Non_GIS_Data.how can i use this extention to store layer password?

Comment: `m_value1` in the example could be a password.  It might be easier to have `m_value1` store the entire propertyset though.